# Remover elemento no interop

Tags: c#, interop

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta que irá gerar um arquivo em formato .DOC, os campos do formulário serão preenchidos de qualquer forma porém gostaria de colocar uma formatação que remova qualquer simbolo do texto.

Ex: " • ", "¹²³£¢¬"

```
var atividades = wordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(); 
atividade.Range.Text = "ATIVIDADES: \t" + txtAtividades.Text.Trim(); 
atividade.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"; 
atividade.Range.Bold = 0; 
atividade.Range.Font.Size = 11; // Centralizando o texto 
atividade.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignPa‌​ragraphLeft; 
atividade.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Comment: Você já tem algum código pronto para que eu possa escrever uma resposta baseada nele?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu lugar, eu aplicaria uma expressão regular para remover caracteres estranhos do texto:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

atividade.Range.Text = Regex.Replace(atividade.Range.Text, "[^0-9a-zA-Z\.,]+", "");
```